# First line of the address is not displayed in sales order?

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, sales-order

I can not get the first line of the address in receiver and sender address in sales -> order.
[image]

But when I click edit, it displays all the address line which I have given

[image]

Now I want to display the first line address in **street address** field in **1st line** in the first image I have uploaded in back-end(admin). Kindly help me!! Spending more than 3 days:(

Comment: Just an idea: Maybe the "#" is interpreded as comment somewhere. Did you check your source-code?

Comment: Nope, tried that. Works for me.

Comment: its coming in local.i have also checked it.but in some case it is not displaying

Comment: @ Anna Völkl other than # is also not displaying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address layout is build thru the System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Address Template configuration page. The Sales Order page uses the HTML Template, so check if the street1 line is included there. The default template for the HTML format is:

```
{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}
{{depend vat_id}}<br/>VAT: {{var vat_id}}{{/depend}}
```

The configuration option is added in a later version (not sure when), so its also possible that the address template is used from the database table directory_country_format (where type=html).

Comment: ok @Vladimir Kerkhoff.I'll check it

Comment: Perfect it works me @Vladimir Kerkhoff